# Stored procedures with WebMatrix/SQL Compact Edition

Tags: webmatrix

I am trying to create a simple application using the WebMatrix tool & Razor syntax. Hence learning a bit of Razor. I dont see a feature to create/call stored procedure's. Is this not supported?

Comment: Note that if you do want to use the Database helper to call a store procedure in a database that supports them, you need to use EXEC eg db.Query("EXEC usp_GetMyStuff"). The Database Helper doesn't allow you to alter the CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Compact (the default database for ASP.NET Web Pages) does not support Stored Procedures.  If you have access to SQL Server, you can use Stored Procedures in it (and it's full supported in ASP.NET Web Pages).

Answer (score 1):

First create a connection to SQL Server that supports Stored Procedures. See example below of entry in web.config file that WebMatrix can create for you.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="trusted_connection=True;server=.\;database=YourDB" name="YourDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Second, connect to and run your Stored Procedure as in example below.

```
@{
  var db = Database.Open("YourDB");
  string YourSP = String.Format("EXEC dbo.YourSP");
  db.Execute(YourSP);
}
```

Third, output results of YourSP to verify everything worked.

```
<table class="table-data">
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var row in db.Query(YourSP))
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@row.YourQueryFieldName</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```